# How to avoid C++ ODR violation in case of multiple operator overloads for the same type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, one-definition-rule

I have a problem with ODR violation in case of multiple implementation of an operator for the same type in different translation units but in the same build target.

#### Example:

Module Test.exe is being compiled with Test1.cpp and Test2.cpp. Which are use common type **TYPE**

```
struct TYPE
{
   FieldType1 Field1
   ...
   FieldTypeN FieldN
};
```

Test1.cpp and Test2.cpp implement specific **operator==()** for **TYPE** to compare **TYPE** only in terms of some values. For example I need to check only **Id** field and don't want to fill all another fields to keep test short and clear. The same for another operators like **operator<<()**

Both test files uses external test library(BOOST TEST, hippomock, etc) which uses **operator==()** for types comparison. When I try to build test I have an error about multiple definition (or just random linked function in case of MSVC).

I've tried to place each operator into the separate namespace and then type

```
using namespace::operator==;
```

inside *.cpp file but it doesn't help.

Is it possible to avoid this issue?

Comment: Yes, this is a violation of ODR rule. No, there is no solution rather than stop defining globally visible operator== for the same type in two TUs.

Comment: Why can you not merely consolidate the two definitions into one file?

Comment: Why do you even have two *different* equality operators for the *same* type?

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas
This is absolutely different modules tests that use shared data type but need to compare it in the different manner.

Comment: It would seem that you are trying to outsmart a poorly-written library.  Does this library work with multiple types, or only your one `TYPE`?

Comment: @DrewDormann I've updated my request. This library is "boost test" and I would like to use BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL macro for example.

Comment: the way to avoid it is to not provide multiple implementations. Even if you could find a way to workaround the rules of the language you would still be left with the confusing fact of having multiple implementations of the same operator

Comment: @user463035818
Yes, I agree with you. I think it will be mach more bedder way to provide functor ussage mechanism but I can't change test framework implementation. As a workaround I use next solution:
I defined a similar comparison macro and moved operator in anonimous namespace. This works but sometimes similar macro definition is not trivial. Also I always should keep it in mind I need to use my own macro. If You put your comment to answers I'll apply it.